# TypeError: function is not a function

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Doing some jasmine testing with JS. So I have the testing function which seems reasonable(only running the first test currently)

```
describe('Anagram', function() {

  it('no matches',function() {
    var subject = new Anagram('diaper');
    var matches = subject.matches([ 'hello', 'world', 'zombies', 'pants']);

    expect(matches).toEqual([]);
  });
```

Then I have my simple function

```
var Anagram = function(string){
    this.word = string;
};

Anagram.prototype.matches = function(array){
    var answer = [];
    var splitWord = this.word.split('').sort();
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var isAnagram = true;
        var splitItem = array[i].split('').sort();
        for(var j = 0; j < splitWord.length; j++){
            if(splitWord[j] !== splitItem[j]){
                isAnagram = false;
            }
        }
        if(isAnagram === true){
            answer.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return answer;
};

module.export = Anagram;
```

My function is supposed to take a string and then look at an array of strings and return the anagram strings. I keep getting TypeError: Anagram is not a function. Tried looking for answers and most of it seemed to relate to semi colons which I think are not an issue since I use one after variable declaration and method declaration. I'd really just like to know what that typeError means if it's a common one to know or what the most likely reasons to get it are.

Comment: Did you declare `Anagram` before using it? I mean, it should be before in the code.

Comment: > `module.export` (typo)

Comment: damnit. of course. even looked at that briefly. thank you

Answer (score 0):

To check whether two strings are anagram or not, one can use this function. If the strings are anagram, then it will return true.

```js
function isAnagram(str1,str2){

    // str to alphabet array
    let arr1 = Array.from(str1);
    let arr2 = Array.from(str2);
//checking length
    let n1 = arr1.length;
    let n2 = arr2.length;
    if (n1 !== n2){
        return false;
    }
    //sorting array
    arr1.sort();
    arr2.sort();
    for (let i=0; i<n1; i++ ){
        if ( arr1[i] !== arr2[i]){
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}

// Example: checking "listen and silent

console.log(isAnagram("listen", "silent"));
```